# Django Detail view query - filter by foreign key objects textchoices field

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

i have the following 2 models - ToDoList and Tasks. Tasks has a Foreignkey to the model ToDoList. In my Detailview I only want to show Tasks, which are published (status="published").

I tried to override the get context data of the view. This worked. But it doesnt show any tasks instances in the Detailview at all, even though I have for example 1 task set as "published".

I also tried to do the filter criteria in the template. I guess this isnt possible? Iam more or less sure the filter criteria must appear in the queryset.

```
class ToDoList(TimeStamp):


    class STATUS(models.TextChoices): 
        PUBLISHED = "published", "Published" 
        TRASH = "trash", "Trash"
        WORKINGDRAFT = "workingdraft", "Workingdraft" 


    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField("Status", max_length=20, choices=STATUS.choices, default=STATUS.PUBLISHED)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('notepad:todo_detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class Tasks(TimeStamp):

    class STATUS(models.TextChoices): 
        PUBLISHED = "published", "Published" 
        TRASH = "trash", "Trash"
        WORKINGDRAFT = "workingdraft", "Workingdraft" 


    todos = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    todolist = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tasks')
    status = models.CharField("Status", max_length=20, choices=STATUS.choices, default=STATUS.PUBLISHED)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.todos
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import ToDoList, Tasks
from .forms import ToDoListForm

class ToDoDetailView(DetailView):
    model = ToDoList
    template_name = 'notepad/notepad_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(ToDoDetailView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['tasks_published'] = self.object.tasks.filter(status="published")
        return context    

    def get_object(self):
        object = super(ToDoDetailView, self).get_object()
        object.num_tasks = object.tasks.all().count()
        return object
```

template

```
<!-- templates/books/book_detail.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ object.headline }}{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="book-detail">
<h2><a href="">{{ object.headline }}</a></h2> 
<p>Author: {{ object.author }}</p> 
<p>Created at: {{ object.created }}</p>

<p>Total Tasks: {{ object.num_tasks }}</p>



<div>
    <h3>Tasks</h3> <ul>
    {% for todo in tasks_published %}
    <li>{{ todo.todos }}</li> 
    {% endfor %}
    </ul> </div>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-primary"
href="{% url 'notepad:todo_list' %}" role="button">
Back to ToDo List
</a> </p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance for your time and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(ToDoDetailView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['tasks_published'] = self.object.tasks.filter(status=STATUS.PUBLISHED)
    return context
```

Because in your code you'll have list of ToDoList instances instead of tasks. And in DetailView() you need to see published tasks for current TodoList, right?

Comment: thank you very much. this gave me following error : name 'STATUS' is not defined. But the "self.object.tasks" was what i missed. The correct query is: context['tasks_published'] = self.object.tasks.filter(status="published"). I edit my question.

Comment: Try to import STATUS in views

Answer (score 1):

try following choice tuple in your `CharField` change choices attribute to i give tuple

```
#define_tuple
PUBLISHED = (
    ('published','Published'),
    ('trash','Trash'),
    ('workingdraft','Workingdraft'),
)

class ToDoList(TimeStamp):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #change in following line 
    status = models.CharField("Status", max_length=20, choices=PUBLISHED, default='published') #here change

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

Try out in both model and check it's work perfect or not let me know